# Odd Flagging Behavior

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is serially flagging posts by a single user ok?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120794/is-serially-flagging-posts-by-a-single-user-ok)
>   [Please stop the massive deletion on a Stack Overflow user's answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/please-stop-the-massive-deletion-on-a-stack-overflow-users-answers)

Last night (5:30am GMT / 12:30am EST) I went into the 10K flags queue and saw about 40 "Not an Answer" flags.  A clear majority of them were flags on answers from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595253/dee), and virtually all of the answers were old.  Clearly an ambitious young flagger went through this user's answers and dropped a ton of flags.

*Most* of these flags were legitimate, since the answers were link-only, sometimes only a link to Google results at that.  But some answers were borderline, and many of the borderline answers had upvotes and or accepts.  I really tried to go out of my way to give this user every benefit of the doubt, and disputed a fair number of the flags.

My question is, is this flagging behavior acceptable?  Should tearing through one user's account *looking* for flags be encouraged or discouraged?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120794/is-serially-flagging-posts-by-a-single-user-ok - relates to the same user I think

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/please-stop-the-massive-deletion-on-a-stack-overflow-users-answers