# Serially flagging for a single user on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Could be possible duplicate with my post [What should we do when a single user has pending flags on many of their answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120806/what-should-we-do-when-a-single-user-has-pending-flags-on-many-of-their-answers) and with related thread [Is serially flagging posts by a single user ok?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120794/is-serially-flagging-posts-by-a-single-user-ok/120865#120865)

Again someone is multi flagging posts by a particular user [@himanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934123/himanshu) and in the [Review queue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=notananswer) they have flagged these post (as not an answer)

- [ListView not appearing in application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259999/714968)
- [How to implement Drag and Drop in android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306298/714968)
- [How to add an OnCLickListener to a widget in a custom listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306271/714968)
- [How to add text or image to customized listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9292814/714968)
- [Efficient way to display the List View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260715/714968)

I've marked these post with `invalid flag` and my post here could be only for notifying about multi-flaging by a single user

Comment: They're all link only and look NAA to me.

Comment: Wow, in a random sample of ten of his answers, nine contained links and no other useful content.  That said, most of the links were actually relevant.  The user doesn't *seem* to be a spammer.  However, the answers were little more than a link, making them not answers at all at the very minimum.

Comment: The user does know how to answer - other answers do have code etc. Left comment on a few answers about the dangers of link only answers

Comment: @ChrisF Unfortunately I had to delete a few of your helpful comments when converting some of the answers to .. well .. helpful comments :) I have pinged the user multiple times, if they want to expand those answers I'll happily restore them.

Comment: @TimPost - no worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've left several comments for this user when converting many of the link only answers to comments. It's not the end of the world, if the user wants to spend some time expanding the answers, they can do that and then flag them to be restored. Meanwhile, the useful links remain in plain view for others to find and appreciate.

We have received multiple flags on many of the answers (which is unnecessary noise), as well as flags from users on a single answer alerting us to go through the rest. We much prefer the latter. The amount of flags in the queue today (from people that have high flag weight) actually obfuscated several *much* more important flags that needed to be dealt with quickly.

As I said in my answer to the question that you referenced, if you see a *trend*, flag once and let us know to take a peek. It helps to ensure that we keep a handle on minor things like this without burying more important things in the process.

Comment: +1 agreed, I disregarding rulles by default but I hate these types of nature ---> I love short answers with link to the `tutorial` or `example code_depots` because at 99,99pct there were real problem anywhere and not rellated with asked question and posted answers, then by default I can't see reasons post different type of answer, nor post good code to very `w*i*d*e` questions, since I never ever down_vote (leaving that for Gods) but I'm sure serially `down_voting` is better as `multi_flagging`, very nice forum looks like as here is pretty possible 10k user per one month :-)

Comment: Well, we _do_ reward people for accurate flagging, and all of the flags were accurate. My only gripe is that the rewards sometimes encourage people to 'pile on', when in fact a single flag telling us to dig through a user's history would suffice. But, that's just finding a balance between encouraging people to flag until they run out of flags, and keeping the noise in the queue at a manageable level.

Answer (score 2):

They're all [link only and thus NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) - there's no indication that they answer the question and there's no assurance on the lifetime of the link.

If there's a lot from one particular user is flagging all of them one by one the best way of handling the issue? Probably not, a single flag explaining the issue would have been sufficient and can include links to searches, e.g. `url:"*example.com*"` (provided [you manually convert any * to %2A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108466/the-free-form-text-in-other-flag-broke-a-pasted-url) in the URL)

Are the flags invalid because of this though? Not really. Could it be better handled? Yes.

(From what I saw the scale is quite different from the previous example you linked to - there were only a handful of flags this time whereas in the previous example there were close to 50)